# bad performance using tf dataset cache in an active learning framework

Tags: python, tensorflow, caching, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to build an input pipeline for an active learning application.
The script I wrote is loading in the data, augmenting and then caching it.

I cache the whole dataset once and then split it up in an unlabeled and a labeled dataset, from where on I transfer samples from one dataset to the other in every iteration.

After a few iteration the training gets extremely slow. The training time per sample is quadrupling after about 20 iterations, which is unacceptable for my model. I can see via tensorboard and the used computer ressources that lots of the time the training is idling and GPU is not even used but the CPU and Sysmem usage are really high.

Has anybody had the same problem and can tell me how to fix it? Or any detailled information about how the tensorflow caching is working?

Thanks!

Edit: I split up the dataset using .take() and .skip() and transfer samples using .concatenate()

Edit: these are the three methods I use, they are simplified though. *indexlist* is the list of samples that are to be transfered from unlabeled to labeled dataset

```
def input_pipeline()
        dataset  = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
        dataset = dataset.map(__convert_tf_records, num_parallel_calls=1)
        dataset_bounding_boxes = dataset.map(get_lung_bb,num_parallel_calls=1)

        if not is_training:
            datasets['bounding_box'] = dataset_bounding_boxes

        if params.repeat > 1 and is_training:
            dataset = dataset.repeat(count=params.repeat)
            dataset_bounding_boxes = dataset_bounding_boxes.repeat(count=params.repeat)

        if is_training:
                    dataset = dataset.map(data_aug_rot, num_parallel_calls=1)
                    dataset = dataset.map(data_aug_zoom, num_parallel_calls=1)
                    dataset = dataset.map(data_aug_elastic_deform, num_parallel_calls=1)

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, dataset_bounding_boxes))

        dataset = dataset.map(get_random_patches_fn, num_parallel_calls=1)
        dataset = dataset.unbatch()

        if params.b_shuffle and is_training:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=params.batch_size*5)
        dataset = dataset.batch(params.batch_size)

        if params.b_cache and is_training:
            cache_path = os.path.join(experiment_dir, "cache")
            if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
                os.makedirs(cache_path)
            dataset = dataset.cache(cache_path + '/')
        dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=params.batch_size)

        datasets['patches'] = dataset
        return datasets



def get_trainingdatasets():

    initial_dataset = input_pipeline()
    dataset_all=initial_dataset['patches']
    dataset_all=dataset_all.unbatch()

    for element in dataset_all:
        dataset_size+=1

    dataset_unlabeled=dataset_all.skip( int(dataset_size*args.ds_labeled_perc) ).batch(params.batch_size)
    dataset_labeled=dataset_all.take( int(dataset_size* args.ds_labeled_perc) )
    dataset_labeled= dataset_labeled.shuffle(buffer_size=500, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(params.batch_size)

    return dataset_labeled, dataset_unlabeled

def transfer_samples():

    dataset_unlabeled = dataset_unlabeled.unbatch()
    dataset_labeled = dataset_labeled.unbatch()

    for idx in index_list:
        element_add=dataset_unlabeled.skip(idx).take(1)
        dataset_add_to_labeled =   dataset_add_to_labeled.concatenate(element_add)

    dataset_labeled = dataset_labeled.concatenate(dataset_add_to_labeled)
    dataset_labeled= dataset_labeled.shuffle(buffer_size=params.batch_size*5)

    dataset_labeled = dataset_labeled.batch(params.batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=params.batch_size)
    dataset_unlabeled = dataset_unlabeled.batch(params.batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=params.batch_size)

    return dataset_labeled, dataset_unlabeled
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please share the code?

Comment: Have you run this without the caching?

Comment: I need to run it with caching, firstly because the data augmentation is super slow, also because the data augmentation would be changing the samples every iteration. For the unlabeled dataset, I need them fixed